Children's movie that a robot sings a song about how his son transformed him into a robot

Date : 70~90s
Country of Origin : Not sure, I guess american/french/british
Color : B&W, but not sure
Memorable Scene:

Protagonist(a little boy) fell to the world he never been before, and there he met a robot who can talk. They both row across the lake on a small boat while the robot sings about how his son transformed him into a robot, because he scolded his son for something trivial. I believe that the robot's son acquired a magical power and created a world that the Protagonist fell into.
Was children's movie, no scares. The boy was a real actor but the robot seemed like  a muppet. As the movie goes, I belive the Protagonist fight his way to the son of a Robot to go back to his world.
